# Why does ask.libreoffice.org look so much like SO?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

While looking for some help with LibreOffice, I came across their Q&A site [ask.libreoffice.org](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) which looks very much like sites of the StackExchange network.

The site follows a similar reputation system (called 'karma' over there) and badges are awarded for similar achievements as on SO (badges even have the same name). Upvotes, downvotes, comments; they have it all. Their Help center isn't quite as extensive as the SE network but all in all, it looks very much like one of the SE sites.

But it isn't! The traffic there isn't quite as massive as SO, but it's still an active site.

Does this count as plagiarism? Is this something that SO mods should look into?

Comment: First of all, this issue has nothing specifically to do with SO, thus it would be better asked at meta.SE which is for issues that are not specific to a site. But concerning your question, I doubt SE has a patent on the Q&A model, or on the specific upvote/downvote mechanics. Yes, they obviously used SO as an inspiration, but why shouldn't they be allowed to do that? What exactly are they plagiarizing that is protected in any way?

Comment: Read first what plagiarism is.

Comment: I notice "site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc" at the bottom of this page. Doesn't the mechanics of upvote/downvote and the reputation model come under the purview of site design?

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt: I read the definition of plagiarism [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plagiarize) and since there is no credit given to SE, does that not mean it is indeed plagiarized? Or at least 'copied' if the former is too harsh a word to use in this context.

Comment: How can you say that something was copied basing only on the fact it 'looks similar'? There are hundreds of ways to make something 'look similar' without even copying a single line.

Comment: Legit question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone is free to copy the model of how the sites work. On MSE there's a list of such software: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/167646)

This particular one is powered by Askbot, which is included in the list:

> - **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)**: Python/Django [hosting](http://askbot.com), [code](http://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel), [docs](http://askbot.org/doc/index.html), [import data](http://askbot.org/doc/import-data.html). GPLv3.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.