# Does Stack Overflow have a deal with Splunk?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was trying to look up some information about Splunk and came across [their Q&A page](http://answers.splunk.com/topics/log4j.html).  It pretty much *is* Stack Overflow, except that you have to create your own account over there and "reputation" is called "karma".

Is this a legitimate partnership, or did they just come over, download the HTML/CSS/JS and go to town?  If the latter, is that a valid use of some kind of open Stack Exchange API, or just blatant theft?

Comment: That site looks impressively similar to us.

Comment: I don't see any assets on that site that were taken from SE, which is the only real part of SE that's under copyright.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't think it's scraping.  It's another implementation.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I looked into it further so I removed that comment :) but here might be something of interest http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: It looks to me like an internal implementation of an SE like Q&A to support their product. They also seem to have content which is not on SO. I don't think this is a partnership nor a violation of SE property. It even notes that it was implemented in a different programming language than SE.

Comment: Apparently it's already been answered on [another "copycat" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270696/1435657) that people can do whatever they want, so I'll either delete or VTC as duplicate.  Not sure if this would be useful for a future search on the subject.

Comment: Copy cats? Cool; copy cats that wreck the user experience? :-/  Poor imitation is the highest form of annoyance.

Comment: From their [FAQ](http://answers.splunk.com/page/faq.html): "Yes, but the folks who have high enough reputation to edit your posts will generally only edit them to fix up obvious problems like a code sample that doesn't have correct formatting." The fact that they called it "reputation" instead of "karma" here is an amusing typo.

Comment: Similar stuff here: [netio/products/discussion](http://answers.netio-products.com/de/questions/). Looks like qother site designers find the format helpful.

Comment: If the format works, then it will be imitated. Stack Overflow's format works...-ish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a site where people can go to ask questions and get answers, vote on content, earn points, tag content, etc. are all concepts that have existed *long* before SE came around.  They are certainly not concepts that SE (or anyone else) has patented, or otherwise holds exclusive rights to.

That another site is using these concepts, whether modeled after SE's implementation or not, is certainly not wrong or any type of theft.

Things that someone *couldn't* just take from SE and use in their own implementation would be the SE logo, or certain other graphical assets, or the actual content of the site (questions and answers) each of which have different types of legal restrictions on if (or how) they can be re-used.

Comment: I'm going to upvote and accept your answer, since you're objectively right.  But you have to admit that your second paragraph is a bit of a stretch, considering that the UI and functionality is basically exactly the same.  (I'm assuming since you use the word "wrong" that the paragraph is a moral statement, not a legal one.)

Comment: It would be like if you wrote a novel and someone took it, changed the title and all the proper nouns in it, and started profiting off of it.

Comment: @asteri It's extremely important for people to be able to use and build off of the ideas of others.  Innovation effectively *requires* this ability.  SE wouldn't be able to exist had it not been able to re-use and re-imagine these same ideas from other implementations here.  Do you consider SE to be stealing from Wikipedia, Reddit, traditional forums, etc.?

Comment: @Servy While I don't disagree with your answer, take a look at somebody's [user page](http://answers.splunk.com/users/199341/jreuter_splunk.html). It's blatantly a rip off of SE's design.

Comment: @Servy There's a huge difference between building off of a concept and doing the exact same thing down to every detail.  A huge difference.  If I made a Reddit clone and called it "AsteriDit" and called their karma "reputation", that's not innovation.

Comment: @asteri You realize that the vast majority of the works of entertainment you've ever enjoyed have been more or less just re-using the plot, mechanics, ideas, etc. of other works?  True original works, devoid of derivative works, basically don't exist.

Comment: @Servy That has nothing to do with this argument, since that's based in human psychology and evolution.  (The whole "there are only 12 unique stories in the world" theory.)  You can make that argument if you like, but it's pretty specious to try and draw the analogue here.

Comment: @asteri It's not like they stole SE's code and put in their own logo.  They re-wrote the entire site from scratch, and simply modeled much of the site after SO.  Everything *isn't* the same down to every detail.  If *you* think that their work lacks sufficient originality, you're welcome to that opinion, but it's just that, your opinion.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough.  You're welcome to your own as well, but I believe you'll find yourself in a small minority.